# Bcrypyt and ReactJS issue

Tags: reactjs, bcryptjs

I am trying a POC in react , , I have used react + mysql , and for DB operation I am using sequelize.

My login ,registration etc. working fine , till now I am storing password as plain text in DB.

Now I want to store encrypted password in DB, I have seen couple of example in internet where people are using bcrypt but they are using it on node(server side), i feel it need to encrypted on client(react) side so when we transmit it into network no one can access my password.

I had tried bcrypt into react and able to store my encrypted password into DB. Follwing is the code I had used for same
Generated Salt

```
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
formik.values.password = bcrypt.hashSync(formik.values.password, salt)
```

Now password is encrypted and saved in DB.

But when I am trying to login with the help of same password, either compareSync or comapreasync I am always getting false

```
 const y = bcrypt.compareSync(response.data.password, bcrypt.hashSync(formik.values.password, salt));

          bcrypt.compare(response.data.password, formik.values.password, (err, data) => {
            //if error than throw error
            if (err) throw err;
            if (data) { navigate("DashBoard"); }
          })
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong? Or when we are using Bcrypt do salt need to be same for all?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#to-hash-a-password-1):

`bcrypt.compareSync()`'s first param takes a plain text password:

```
bcrypt.compareSync(myPlaintextPassword, hash);
```

While `bcrypt.hashSync()` will compute and return a hash:

```
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds);
```

As you submit hashed password from client:

```
formik.values.password = hash;
```

The password data from server: `response.data.password`, is actually a hash, not a plain password:

```
bcrypt.compareSync(
  response.data.password, // <- hash value from server
  bcrypt.hashSync(formik.values.password, salt) // <- original hash
);
```

So all you need is to pass in plain text password for it to compare.

> Now password is encrypted and saved in DB.

Technically the password is hashed not encrypted.

#### Difference between Hashing vs Encryption:

1. Hashing: A one-way summary of data, cannot be reversed, used to validate the integrity of data.
2. Encryption: A two-way encoding of data, can be reversed, used to protect confidentiality of data.

<sub><sub><sup>Bonus: hashing is like a meat grinder. You can turn a cow to a hamburger, but not the reverse.</sup></sub></sub>

Read more: [Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms#:%7E:text=Finally%2C%20hashing%20is%20a%20form,%2Dlength%20value%2C%20or%20hash.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not a response to your question.
I'm pinpointing your analysis on the hashing being on the client side.

It's a terrible idea, they can easily have access to your salt value which makes it 10x easier for any brutforce algorithm to go through any combination knowing the salt value.

Hash it in the backend.
Always.

Here's a video showing why people use bcrypt. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6cmuiTBZVs

Eventhough he says that it'll take longer than any other hashing algorithms to go throug the hash even by knowing the salt, it's better that they don't have the salt at the starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS), there is no need to encrypt your password on client side. HTTPS was created for that exact reason.

And if you share logic and secret key for encryption and decryption on both server and client that would make it more vulnerable.